# given some file names, print the total disk usage of these files

Tags: linux

Given a potentially very large list of file names whose files are located in different directories, different naming conventions, etc, how to compute and print the aggregate disk usage for the files? I've been doing it with the following script (which also lists the number of files used in the calculation), but I'm wondering if there's maybe a unix tool that already does this, alternative/simpler ways to do it? Looking at the man page for `ls` it does not appear there is a way to give it a set of filenames and ask it to print just the summary of disk usage.

```
LISTCOUNT=0
LISTSIZE=0
cat /tmp/filelist | while read FF
do
  FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s "$FF")
  LISTSIZE=$[LISTSIZE+${FILESIZE}]
  echo listsize: $LISTSIZE
  LISTCOUNT=$[LISTCOUNT+1]
  echo listcount: $LISTCOUNT
done | tail -2
```

Comment: I can't think of a standard tool that would do all of this ("du -cks" comes close but would need care with filenames containing spaces and very long lists of files). Personal preference would be to split this in two - generate list of sizes and then pipe into awk  to sum.

Comment: yeah ... it's a bit odd that 40 years of unix and there isn't a little tool to do it, ... another open source project to add to my list of things to do !